# What does this mean. "Ce look-là" From french Extra

Tags: grammaire, expressions, pronoms, conjugaison, questions

I know it is wrong to translate from word to word, but can someone shed more light on this, please.

Answer (score 2):

The words *-ci* and *-là* are particles you use with *ce/cette/ces*.  Generally, *cette chose-ci* would be translated as *this thing* and *cette chose-là* would be translated as *that thing*, so *ce look-là* would be *that look*.

If somebody says *cette chose* without a particle (which they actually do most of the time), there are two possibilities:

1. it's completely clear whether they mean *this* or *that* from context, so they don't bother adding the particle,
2. it doesn't make any difference whether you use *this* or *that*, so there's no need for the particle.

There are occasionally cases where French speakers say *cette chose-là* when native English speakers would use *this thing*. I've encountered these cases reading French, and they've puzzled me somewhat, but I'm not a fluent French speaker, so I can't say exactly when this happens.

Comment: Unlike the *this/that* clearly distinct meanings, the form *-là* tends to be used for both in French, possibly because *-ci* is perceived to be more formal. You hear more and more *Tu veux çui-là ou çui-là ?* instead of *Tu veux celui-ci ou celui-là ?*